# How to make Qtip2 Growl start from the bottom

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I been using Qtip2 for almost 2 of my past projects and I want to use this qtip2 trick which is called as Growl http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#growl

now, I really want the growl to start from the bottom and not from above.

I keep on reversing the codes with not luck...

How can I make this start in the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse several top to bottom, bottom to top and reverse the adjust value from y:5 to y:-5 , these changes should work:

```
my: 'bottom right',
```

and

```
at: (target.length ? 'top' : 'bottom') + ' right',
```

and

```
adjust: { y: -5 },
```

and

```
api.set('position.at', 'bottom right');
```